# Bash - cat command and errors

Tags: bash, cat

I was trying bash shell redirection. I have a directory where there is just one file -  a.txt

```
more a.txt
HELLO
```

If I type
`cat  < a.txt   b.txt` , I get

```
cat: b.txt: No such file or directory
```

If I type

```
cat  < a.txt   b.txt a.txt
```

I get

```
cat: b.txt: No such file or directory
HELLO
```

Why am I not seeing HELLO when I try cat < a.txt b.txt? I tried different combinations - typing a.txt multiple times before/after b.txt and see a pattern, but not able to figure out why.

```
cat  <   a.txt a.txt b.txt  
HELLO
cat: b.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `cat` is a program, not something built into Linux. In many cases, it's from GNU, though I could imagine busybox also providing one. Consider fixing that in the title and also removing the "linux" tag, see its description for more. Further, it's not "linux redirection" but a shell feature. Most likely it's ash or bash in your case, but it could also be a different shell. Again, see the description of the "shell" tag why it's usually wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirecting means sending the content of the file into the command's STDIN.

`cat`'s behavior is to read content of file in it's argument(s) to STDOUT. But if there's no argument, then the content is read from STDIN.

See that I write `argument(s)` there? It's because the number of argument can be 0, 1, or multiple.

in simple pseudocode, it's like this:

```
if number of arguments = 0
  print STDIN to STDOUT
else
  for each file in arguments
    print file content to STDOUT
```

Example 1:

`cat a.txt`

output:

`HELLO`

Example 2:

`cat` (then enter)

You will be able to type into terminal, when you click enter, the typed line is sent to `cat`'s STDIN. Then `cat` will print line you just typed.

## Answer

#### So when you type:

`cat  < a.txt   b.txt`

internally, it works like this:

- STDIN is filled with content of a.txt `HELLO` text
- $1 (first argument) is `b.txt` which is a non-existent file

based on behavior above, it will print content of `b.txt` alone since there is 1 argument supplied.

but it doesn't find file `b.txt`, so it outputs an error message.

#### when you type:

`cat  < a.txt   b.txt a.txt`

internally, it works like this:

- STDIN is filled with content of a.txt `HELLO` text
- $1 (first argument) is `b.txt` which is a non-existent file
- $2 (second argument) is `a.txt`

will output: (once again STDIN is ignored because there are 2 arguments)

```
cat: b.txt: No such file or directory
HELLO
```

## More detailed explanation

- when you run command `mycommand arg1 arg2 arg3`, it means there are 3 command line arguments: `arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3` respectively
- STDIN is standard input: data stream for sending input to a command. You can send data to STDIN like these (assuming the target command is `cat`):

  - `echo "my data" | cat`
  - make file called data.txt, filled with `my data`, save it, then use `cat < data.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't use cat the right way.
Cat expects a file or many files as parameter not an data stream.

To show the file with cat use:

```
cat a.txt
```

To Redirect it into file b.txt

```
cat a.txt > b.txt
```

And your last question, with the pattern.

You pass 3 arguments to cat.

Arg1: (`< a.txt`)
Arg2: (`a.txt`)
Arg3: (`b.txt`)

Argument 1 is nonsense Argument 2 a valid file and Arg 3 an incorrect file.

Comment: I usually use cat command the way you have shown. I was just trying simple redirection options for stdout, stderr and observed this behaviour, and got curious.

Comment: It works with less, and more but not with cat cause, as explained cat expects an filepath. Less and more might also handle file paths but can display data streams as well.

Answer (score 0):

`< inputfile` is a redirection. `<` redirects the file `inputfile` into stdin *standard input* of a command. The `<` and `inputfile` are not passed as arguments to the command. The placement doesn't matter, these lines are all exactly *the same*:

```
< inputfile command arg1 arg2
command < inputfile arg1 arg2
command arg1 < inputfile arg2
command arg1 arg2 < inputfile
```

> Why am I not seeing HELLO when I try cat < a.txt b.txt?

From `man cat`:

```
 With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.
```

Because given arguments, cat is not reading from stdin - stdin is ignored. Instead it reads from given `FILE`s on arguments. So `a.txt` on stdin is ignored.

You can do:

```
< a.txt cat - b.txt
# or
cat - < a.txt b.txt
# or
cat - b.txt < a.txt
# or really just
cat a.txt b.txt
```